# Portfolio Overload: Time to Trim or Wait?

Tags: india, nse-india, bse-india

I have recently started investing in **Indian stock market**. It has only been **six** months, and I have invested around `~10L`, sitting at `12%` profit(P/L).
I happened to discover a core problem in my investments, being a noob initially, whenever I found a business fascinating, I would invest in it(`2-3` stocks in the same sector, sometimes more than `3` as well) not thinking about how would my portfolio generate good/greater returns. I never invested in a **Micro-Nano** cap tbh, **Small** cap a few with good business background, but **Mid** and **Large** cap shares is mostly present in my portfolio. I have around `120` holdings as of now. Now, you can imagine I have only invested a small quantity of amount for each positions held, with a few number of shares all together. Fear of money loss kept investments spread thin, hindering potential gains.

I really want to cut my holdings and bring it something around only `10-20` businesses, but what I am worried about is, if I happen to sell most of them, I will be imposed with `15%` **STCG**.
In this bullish market, `12%` profit at an investment of `~10L` is nothing, I feel so. It would have been better had if I simply invested in Nifty 50 or Sensex.

What is your take on this, should I sell most of the shares to bring my holdings down, or should I at least hold for another `6-10 months`, in order to be in a **LTCG** category to be imposed less tax on selling?
Also, it is difficult to time the markets, selling selective things would be difficult for sure and I don't have much knowledge about technical analysis as well, but I can only stick with *monopolies* is what I can think as of now.

Thanks in advance, for helping me out with the above questions!